# Boost logging to file without loosing its content

Tags: c++11, logging, boost

I want to write logs in some file (`logs.log`). But every time I stop and start the application it is rewriting the existing file and not adding logs in it. Is it possible to add the logs in the file (append), and not losing the old ones?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418917/boost-log-how-to-configure-a-text-sink-backend-to-append-to-rotated-files) might be relevant.

Comment: :)) I have just read it... And to me (Boost 1.55, Ubuntu 14) it seems that open_mode works...